# h:commandLink with f:ajax doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2

i use jsf2.0. my code look like this:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:commandButton  value="testbutton" action="#{Bean.test}">
        <f:ajax   render="msg"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:outputText value="#{Bean.outmsg}" id="msg"/>
</h:form>
```

it's working well.
but if i change h:commandbutton to h:commandlink,
code look like this:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:commandLink  value="testbutton" action="#{Bean.test}">
        <f:ajax   render="msg"/>
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:outputText value="#{Bean.outmsg}" id="msg"/>
</h:form>
```

then my code can't work.
i need help,thanks guys.

Comment: What does it mean _my code can't work_? Also show the managed bean.

Comment: mean is change to commandlink , then #{Bean.test} will not be invoked

Answer (score 3):

use this code.

```
<f:ajax event="click" render="msg" listener="#{Bean.test}"/>
```

**should be your java bean side like this.**

```
public void test(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {   }
```